# HTTP ERROR 500 when I define WP_User_Query

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to write a plugin that use WP_User_Query class but when I define it and execute it the website goes on HTTP 500.

Code:

```
add_action('user_register','partner_add_identification_coupon_code');
function partner_add_identification_coupon_code($user_id){

    $user = get_user_by('id',$user_id);
    if( in_array( 'lspt_partner', (array) $user->roles ) || in_array( 'administrator', (array) $user->roles ) ){

        $partner_coupon_id_code= 'PTR'.create_code(9);
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'lspt-codice-id-coupon', $partner_coupon_id_code);

    $args = array(
        'meta_key'   => 'lspt-codice-id-coupon',
        'meta_value' => $partner_coupon_id_code
    );

    $query_partner = WP_User_Query( $args );

    echo $query_partner->get_total();
  }
}
```

Comment: A 500 error is a generic error message and covers pretty much every single thing that can go wrong with a script. Check your server error logs to find out the exact error message.

Comment: Also, if your site is private you could temporarily show the error in the browser by changing this `define('WP_DEBUG', false);` to `define('WP_DEBUG', true);` in your wp-config.php

Comment: I've just tried but I don't receive anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like:

```
$query_partner = WP_User_Query( $args );
```

is missing the `new` keyword.

Should be:

```
$query_partner = new WP_User_Query( $args );
```

Answer (score 0):

Configure php.ini from

```
display_errors Off
```

to

```
display_errors On
```

Will save you a quite a bit of time. Also I'm pretty sure the issue is

```
$query_partner = WP_User_Query( $args );
```

should be

```
$query_partner = new WP_User_Query($args);
```

Comment: Don't change the php.ini if you are on a production server.